# 2 $http get function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

Given 2 JSON url, how do I make sure the code has finished retrieving the data from a.json, then only start retrieving the data from b.json, then only run init function?

```
var aUrl = "a.json";
var bUrl = "b.json";
```

My attempt:

```
var app = angular.module('calendarApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) { 
  $http.get(aUrl).success(function(data) {   }); 
  $http.get(bUrl).success(function(data) {  
   init()}
);
var init = function(){}
```

Comment: With a promise, which is stands for callbacks.

Comment: you chain them together by putting one inside the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I faced the same issue in my initial days.
There are many ways of doing it exactly as suggested here.
You need to know below two things before exploring:
```

**1. JavaScript is synchronous**

```
Synchronous Example[Flow in sequence]:
       console.log('1')
       console.log('2')
       console.log('3')
```

> It logs 1 2 3.

Example of making service calls

```
   1. $http.get(aUrl).success(function(data) {  console.log('1.any time response returns')  });  
   2. $http.get(bUrl).success(function(data) { console.log('2.mummy returns')};
```

So as single-threaded javascript will first make a call to your below code with $http.get(aUrl) which hits the url and processes to fetch the data from the background.

1. $http.get(aUrl).success(function(data) {  console.log('1.any time response returns')   });

But the key thing to notice here is $http.get(aUrl) requested above doesn't wait until the data is returned in success/error. It moves to the next request $http.get(bUrl) and we just can't predict which response comes earlier.

2. $http.get(bUrl).success(function(data) { console.log('2.mummy returns') }

Output might be either

> 1.any time response returns
>
> 2.mummy returns

```
                     or
```

> 2.mummy returns
>
> 1.any time response returns

So, to overcome this situation we follow asynchronous operations in various ways.

**2. Asynchronous Calls**

```
$http.get(aUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log('inside the first then response');
      console.log(response.data);

      //executing the second request after we get the first request
     //and returns the **outputResponse** which is captured in the next **then** block
      return $http.get(bUrl);
    })
    .then(function(**outputResponse** ){
      console.log('outputResponse generated from to the second bUrl');
      //you can call init() here 
    });
```

Above code suffices your requirement.

[Click for more info using $q in future](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

[Click here to know why to use then instead of success.](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promises%E2%80%93then-vs-success)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best or cleanest method but quickly making your code do what you want it to do I got:

```
var app = angular.module('calendarApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) { 
  $http.get(aUrl).success(function(data) {   
      $http.get(bUrl).success(function(data) {  
         init()
      }
  }); 
);
var init = function(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service layer in which define the two methods. Then inject the service into your controller:

```
//Controller
YourService.getUrl(urlA).then(function(response) {

            if(response != null && response.success == true){
                // do something
            }
            YourService.getUrl(urlB).then(function(response) {

                if(response != null && response.success == true){
                    // do something
                    init()
                }
            }, 
            function errorCallback(response) {

                console.log("Error YourService: getUrlB ---> ");
            }); 
        }, 
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Error YourService: getUrlA ---> ");
        });

// Example of method in your service    
this.getUrl = function(urlA) {
    try{
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: getUrlA,
            params: {},
            responseType: "json",
            cache: false
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            deferred.reject(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }catch(e){
        /* */
        console.log("Service: getUrl ---> " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*$http.get* returns a promise, so you can do:

```
return $http.get(aUrl)
    .then(function(result) {
        return $http.get(bUrl);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        return init();
    },
    function (error) {
        // do something with the error
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use AngularJS promises. Mainly it has the benefit of loading the data asynchronly at the same time without having to wait until the first request is finished. see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```js
var promises = [];

var loadingJson = function(url){
  var defer = $q.defer();

  $http.get(url).then(function(results){
    defer.resolve(results);
  }, function(err){
    defer.reject(err);
  });

  return defer.promise;
};

promise.push(loadingJson('example.com/1.json'));
promise.push(loadingJson('example.com/2.json'));

$q.all(promises).then(function(resultList){
  // Your hanadling here, resultList contains the results of both API calls.
}, function(errList){
  // Your error handling here.
});
```

Comment: This can be either in your controller or put into a seperate serivce as well. Which would make the stuff better testable if needed.

Comment: For the resultList, does resultList[0] always return result from 1.json and resultList[1] always return result from 2.json? How do I know for sure which one has result from 1.json, and which has result from 2.json?