# ngFor Array not updating DOM view angular 5. Updating dom on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I am getting contacts list using contact api.

```
contacts = new Array<Object>();
public signIn() {
    this.getContacts().then((res)=>{
        console.log("res",res);
        this.contacts =res;
    })
}
```

and here is my html

```
<button (click)="signIn()">Import google contacts</button>
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    {{contact}}
</div>
```

The problem is when I click sign in button on first time, the html DOM View is not updated. But when I click 2nd time, then it DOM html view is updated. I want it to be updated on first time. Can anybody help?

Here is my getContact function. I am using jquery inside.

```
public getContacts():any {
    let config = {
        'client_id': 'xxxx',
        'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    };
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, ()=> {                
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=100',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: gapi.auth.getToken()
            }).done(function(data) {
                resolve(data.feed.entry);

            });
        });
    })
  }
```

The response I am getting in first time. Following is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Is the list needs to be updated after some time? In your code, setTimeout() is used. No need for setTimeout.

Comment: no that was deliberately done. It does not need to be updated on timeout. I will remove it.

Comment: Share getContacts() function code

Comment: it is shared now

Comment: question is edited now.

Comment: console.log("res",res); => What it logs?

Comment: Why are you using jquery to make your api call? Have a look at the Angular HttpClient https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Ok long story. i tried all day using http client. The problem is it is jsonp request. I used jsonp angular module as well. But nothing worked. Thats why i finally opted for jquery.

Comment: console.log("res",res); logs are attached in screenshot

Comment: This link might be helpful for you to work with jsonp request.
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/jsonp-with-observables/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `async` pipe in the view side like this -

```
<button (click)="signIn()">Import google contacts</button>
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts | async">
         {{contact}}
</div>

public signIn() {
        this.contacts = this.getContacts();
    }
```

Also No need to use `setTimeout` within your subscription.

Comment: i am getting this error using pipe. "InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: Yes i will remove timeout . It is not working either

Comment: it returns any.

Comment: it is shared now

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts =new   Array<Object>();
    public signIn() {
```

> ```
> this is an async request.So, this.contacts populates after you get result from this.getContacts()
> ```

```
        this.getContacts().then((res)=>{
            console.log("res",res);
            this.contacts =res;
            setTimeout(()=>{
```

> You are recalling the signIn again, don't know why it is required!
>   Removing timeout code should bring you out of mess.

```
 this.contacts =res;
                    this.signIn();
                },2000);
                this.flag =1;
            })

        }
```

Comment: Thas was done delibrately. I will remove it. I pasted it wrong here.

Comment: That should be great. Did you try removing the setTimeout block? Just would like to know is the issue still existing after that.

Comment: Yes it exists. I was trying to solve it by adding timeout. but that didn't help

Comment: Can you please let us know in your first click, what is log response for the line -> console.log("res",res); similarly for your second click.

Comment: screenshot is attached

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't access it. $http.get(aUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log('inside the first then response');
      console.log(response.data);

      //executing the second request after we get the first request
     //and returns the **outputResponse** which is captured in the next **then** block
      return $http.get(bUrl);
    })
    .then(function(**outputResponse** ){
      console.log('outputResponse generated from to the second bUrl');
      //you can call init() here 
    });

Comment: Give a try with regular ajax or $http get post calls to cross verify with gapi. This is only in trying to figure out where  the issue is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247687/2-http-get-function/50254410#50254410